# Check If User Input Is Empty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble checking whether the input field is empty and when it is I want to revert it to the content in the h1 tag.

```
<body>
    <h1>Enter Your Username</h1>
    <input type="text" id="username" />
  </body>

const input = document.querySelector("input");
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");

input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  h1.innerText = `Welcome ${input.value}`;
});

if (input.length === 0) {
  h1.innerText = "Enter Your Username";
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use always textContent instead of innerText

Comment: Instead of checking the value via JavaScript you could also simply add the `required` attribute to the input element.

Answer (score 3):

input has not length property. You probably meant:

```
if (input.value.length === 0) {
  h1.innerText = "Enter Your Username";
}
```

or without whitespaces: (thanks to [Roko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66786436/check-if-user-input-is-empty/66786461#comment118058537_66786461))

```
if (input.value.trim().length === 0) {
      h1.innerText = "Enter Your Username";
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to trim()

Answer (score 1):

Currently the input length check is not inside the event handler. Ideally you want to check if the input is empty every time the input value changes. So you want it inside your input.addEventListener callback

```
input.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  h1.innerText = this.value.length === 0 ?
    "Enter Your Username" :
    `Welcome ${input.value}`; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
**HTML**
<body>
    <h1>Enter Your Username</h1> 
    <input type="text" id="username">
</body>

**JS** 
let inputEl = document.querySelector('input') 

let h1 = document.querySelector('h1') 
inputEl.addEventListener('input',()=>{ 
  h1.innerText = "Welcome, " + inputEl.value 
 if (inputEl.value.length === 0) h1.innerText = "Enter Your Username";
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).